# Help with Kaggle Data Set

Tags: data-transformation, image-processing, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm doing the following competition on Kaggle

https://www.kaggle.com/c/street-view-getting-started-with-julia/details/knn-tutorial

Its data set consists of bmp images of size 20x20 and we are required to use KNN as the algorithm. Now since KNN works with Euclidean Distances, I'm not able to figure out how should I give images as an input to KNN? How should I select the features and convert the images into vector representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library in your programming environment (e.g. [python](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/), [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), etc.) to read and store the RBG values of the bitmap into a data structure. For example, you might use a multidimensional array wherein each row is an image of the training set. You can perform the Euclidean distance calculation between the columns for each row.

Here is an example using python:

```
from scipy import misc
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

im_a = misc.imread('1.png') # this reads the image into a np array
im_b = misc.imread('2.png')

euclidean(im_a[0,0,0], im_b[0,0,0]) # calc distance of pixel at same location of a and b
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more or provide me a link from where I can learn by doing?

Comment: I don't know what your language of choice is. If you're using Python, take a look at the 'python' link from my answer - I provided a simple example above as well.